# How to fix "Assertion '__pos <= size' failed" error?

Tags: c++, string, iostream

I'm trying to write a function that compares two strings, say, `s1` and `s2`, and if at some position, `s1[i] == s2[i]`, then it must increase a counter by one (i.e. it counts the number of cases which at the same position (say, `i`), they contain the same characters).

The code I'm using:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int posicions_iguals(string s1, string s2)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); ++i){
    if (s1[i] == s2[i])
      ++count;
  }
  return count;
}

int main()
{
  string s1;
  string s2;
  while (cin >> s1) {
    cin >> s2;
    cout << posicions_iguals(s1, s2) << endl;
  }
}
```

If the size of the first string is greater than the size of the second one (i.e. `s1.size() > s2.size()`), I get the error below:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:846: std::basic_string<_CharT, 
_Traits, _Alloc>::reference std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, 
_Alloc>::operator[](std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) 
[with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = 
std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, 
_Alloc>::reference = char&; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, 
_Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the bar as length of smaller string:-

```
  int count = 0;
  int length = (s1.size() < s2.size()) ? s1.size() : s2.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
    if (s1[i] == s2[i]) 
      ++count;
  }
  return count;
```

Comment: Can you explain what this line does?

Comment: Here length would be the size of smaller string so that it will be in bounds of both strings...In your case there are chances that you would cross the bound of one string if you take into account length of larger string.

Comment: using min() may have been clearer than the (:?) syntax.

Comment: @aleixrr - it's a short-form of an if-else block.  `x==y?true:false;` -> `if (x==y) return true; else return false;`